# Check element for css values?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

example:  Can I just if a div tag has the css of

```
div{background-color: #444444}
```

and return true/false depending on the result?

I'm using watir webdriver to run testing scripts, I need to check values of css to and see if the changes have been applied etc.

Comment: Can you explain what you need?

Comment: @AvinVarghese I'm using watir, I just need to select the tag and check the css values and compare and return true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watir-webdriver has a built in [`style`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#style-instance_method) method for getting the computed styles.

Get the style using:

```
div.style('background-color')
```

This will return a string representing the computed style's value. You can then compare that to your expected value.

Comment: hm, so you can not choose the value of the attribute? maybe like div.style('background-color:#444444') ?

Comment: An element can only have one value per style property. To do the comparison, do `div.style('background-color') == "#444444"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mix Nokogiri (HTML parser) and  CSSPool (CSS parser) to looks for the style and for any element with that selector in the body.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this with Javascript:

```
var bg = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(yourElement).getPropertyValue('background-color');
if (bg == '#444444'){
// do your code here
}
```

You may need to check this for older browsers.